# Ajax.BeginForm not catching OnSuccess with jQuery UI dialog in MVC?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am loading partial view with Jquery UI dialog. In partialview post submit I want capture results in `updateSuccess` function. But function was never called and results was showing on page.

### Parent page

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

            function display_dialog() {

               $('#my-dialog').dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    modal: true,
                    show: "blind",
                    hide: "blind",
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).load("/ContactSubmission/Index" );
                    }
                });

     function updateSuccess(data) {
                if (data.Success == true) {
                    alert("Inside Update");
                    //now we can close the dialog
                  $('#my-dialog').dialog( "close" );
                    //twitter type notification
                    $('#commonMessage').html("Update Complete");
                    $('#commonMessage').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(3000).slideUp(400);
                } else {
                    $("#update-message").html(data.ErrorMessage);
                    $("#update-message").show();
                }
            }
  </script>
```

### controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var contact = new Contact
  {
        Countries = Context.GetCountries()
   };           
    return PartialView(contact);
}
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(Contact contact)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     if (contact != null)
     {
         //Some business logic is here
         var result = new { Success = "True", Message = "No Error" };
         return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
     }
     else{
         var result = new { Success = "False", Message = "Contact is Null" };
         return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
     }
   }
   else
   {
      var result = new { Success = "False", Message = "Invalid state" };
      return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
  }
```

### Partial view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "ContactSubmission", new AjaxOptions{ 
           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST",
           OnSuccess = "updateSuccess" },new { enctype = "multipart/form-data",
           @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
  {
      // Html code is here
       <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-offset-5">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="cancel">Cancel
            </button>
          </div>
       </div>           
    }
```

after submit is showing like this on browser

[image]

How can I handle the issue and how to call function after submit results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference jquery Unobtrusive otherwise the view will change.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive/

This has caught me out before and as a result I find it much easier to write my own ajax calls in jQuery so I dont need this reference.

Good Luck

Comment: @james123 

You can install it using nuget package console within visual studio or you can download it or reference a CDN. Go here http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDN.ashx and reference the right one.

Once that's referenced it will work straight away. Make sure your reference is after your jquery reference

Comment: I installed Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive 3.0 , But I don't see any JS file. Package.config has reference.

Comment: Check Scripts/Imported Libraries This is normally where nuget puts your js files. you will need to reference this script in your view as well

Comment: I got it. Do I need to include this after ` @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

Comment: @James123 - No worries glad you got it sorted :)